# What is the last Tony Hawk Game to come out on PC?

Tags: windows-7, tony-hawks-pro-skater

What is the last Tony Hawk Game to come out on PC?

I used to love playing those games and wanted to know if they are still around and do they work on windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last Game that came out on PC was Tony Hawk's Pro Skater HD:

http://store.steampowered.com/app/207210/

It works well on Windows 7, since it was a fresh remake with the Unreal Engine.